# Best practice for mutual referenced structs that invoke each other

Tags: rust

After many hours, I still didn't figure out a (nice) way to solve the problem that a struct A uses a helper struct B that is configured by A so that B has an async callback to A:

```rust
// Helper for struct DeviceModel. An async timer, such as a thread.
trait AsyncTimer {
    // Set a timeout. After that, code code behind callback should be 
    // executed. The closure owns Arc<DeviceModel> to operate on DeviceModel
    // and to ensure its lifetime.
    fn configure_timeout(&self, duration: Duration, callback: Box<dyn Fn()>);
}

struct AsyncTimerImpl {
    // impl details for thread handling 
}

impl Asynctimer for AsyncTimerImpl {
   fn configure_timeout(&self, duration: Duration, callback: Box<dyn Fn()>) {
     // set next timeout when the thread should call `callback`
   }
}

struct DeviceModel {
    // Device model owns this relation. AsyncTimer must also be 
    able to asyncorunously call something on device model.
    async_timer: Box<dyn AsyncTimer>
}

impl DeviceModel {
    fn setup_next_timeout(&self) {
      let this = /* ... */; // actually, I need an Arc here instead of &self...
      let cb = Box::new(move || this.handle_timeout() );
      async_timer.configure_timeout(Duration::from_secs(1), cb);
    }
    fn handle_timeout(&self) {}
}
```

The problem is the following:
`DeviceModel` can call `self.async_timer.configure_timeout()` which will affect the behavior of the thread running behind the `AsyncTimerImpl` struct. When the thread fires the next event, it should invoke an action on `DeviceModel`. `DevideModel` should be responsible for defining an arbitrary computation on itself.

However, I'm suffering from cyclic dependency problems as `DeviceModel` needs to change the state of `AsyncTimer` and the callback passed to `AsyncTimer` must invoke code inside `DeviceModel`:

1. You can't have `Arc<>` in both directions, as it can leak memory
2. Having `Arc<AsyncTimer>` in `DeviceModel` and `Weak<DeviceModel>` in `AsyncTimerImpl`  solves 1) but still requires very ugly lazy initialization of both structs.

I want `DeviceModel` to have full control over `configure_timeout` as well as the callback action but this seems impossible to solve.

Any ideas, my fellow Rustaceans?
PS: AsyncTimer is not supposed to live any longer than the corresponding DeviceModel. It would be fine to have a lifetime connection.

Comment: Another idea that I have: maybe I have to change the interface to have a function such as dispatch_async_task(). Then, if I'm not mistaken, I do have much more control over everything as I can pass &self to the callback. Lifetime is insured by the DeviceModel strict which would own it's device thread in that case..

Comment: What do you mean by "very ugly lazy initialization"?

Comment: The problem that `Arc::new_cyclic` solves. This is the solution I was looking for which makes everything much easier. Please have a look at the solution of @bk2204.

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately, Rust has just the thing for you: [`Arc::new_cyclic`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.new_cyclic).  This uses `Arc` and `Weak` together, and is specifically designed to work with cyclic data structures like you have here.

Your code could look a little like this:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Weak};
use std::time::Duration;

// Helper for struct DeviceModel. An async timer, such as a thread.
trait AsyncTimer {
    // Set a timeout. After that, code code behind callback should be
    // executed. The closure owns Arc<DeviceModel> to operate on DeviceModel
    // and to ensure its lifetime.
    fn configure_timeout(&self, duration: Duration, callback: Box<dyn Fn()>);
}

struct AsyncTimerImpl {
    device_model: Weak<DeviceModel>,
    // impl details for thread handling
}

impl AsyncTimer for AsyncTimerImpl {
    fn configure_timeout(&self, duration: Duration, callback: Box<dyn Fn()>) {
        // set next timeout when the thread should call `callback`
    }
}

struct DeviceModel {
    // Device model owns this relation. AsyncTimer must also be able to asyncorunously call something on device model.
    async_timer: Arc<dyn AsyncTimer>,
}

impl DeviceModel {
    fn setup_next_timeout(self: Arc<Self>) {
        let this = Arc::clone(&self);
        let cb = Box::new(move || this.handle_timeout());
        self.async_timer
            .configure_timeout(Duration::from_secs(1), cb);
    }
    fn handle_timeout(&self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let dm = Arc::new_cyclic(|me| DeviceModel {
        async_timer: Arc::new(AsyncTimerImpl {
            device_model: me.clone(),
        }),
    });
}
```

The only constraint is that this requires Rust 1.60 or newer, but unless you have strong compatibility requirements, this should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a variant that is somehow cursed and uses unsafe Rust, but **I think**, it is safe (miri reports it is not safe, and it is indeed very cursed what I do there). But with control flow in mind, it should work.

TL;DR: `trait AsyncTimer` has a function  `fn set_timeout(&self, timestamp: Duration, cb: Box<dyn Fn() + Send>)`. To create that callback in  `device_model.set_timeout()`, one can do this crude hack

```rust
fn set_next_timeout(&self) {
        let cb = {
            // This hack is only valid, as the device model and it's thread have a shorter
            // lifetime than the device model. This is enforced by control flow and not by
            // Rust's type system and lifetime logic.
            //
            // Otherwise, it is far from trivial to move a callback to the device model.
            let self_cursed: &'static DeviceModel<T> = unsafe { &*core::ptr::addr_of!(*self) };
            move || {
                self_cursed.on_timeout();
            }
        };
        let cb = Box::new(cb);
        self.timer.set_timeout(Duration::new(1, 0), cb);
    }
```

The whole code can be found on [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c46cc3e8862580ee77314b31c835f20d) or in the following. It produces this output:

```
Timer has fired!
AsyncTimer called callback in DeviceModel
Timer has fired!
AsyncTimer called callback in DeviceModel
Stopped Thread
```

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, AtomicU64, Ordering};
use std::sync::{Arc, Condvar, Mutex, MutexGuard};
use std::thread::sleep;
use std::time::Duration;


/// An async timer that is owned by a device.
trait AsyncTimer: 'static {
    fn new() -> Self
    where
        Self: Sized;
    fn abort_timeout(&self);
    fn set_timeout(&self, timestamp: Duration, cb: Box<dyn Fn() + Send>);
}

struct DeviceModel<T: AsyncTimer> {
    timeout_counter: AtomicU64,
    timer: T,
}

struct AsyncTimerImpl {
    thread_handle: Option<std::thread::JoinHandle<()>>,
    mutex_condvar: Arc<(Mutex<Option<(Duration, Box<dyn Fn() + Send>)>>, Condvar)>,
    exit_thread: Arc<AtomicBool>,
}

impl AsyncTimerImpl {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let mutex_condvar: Arc<(Mutex<Option<(Duration, Box<dyn Fn() + Send>)>>, Condvar)> =
            Arc::new((Mutex::new(None), Condvar::new()));
        let exit_thread = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false));

        let thread_handle = {
            let mutex_condvar = mutex_condvar.clone();
            let exit_thread = exit_thread.clone();

            std::thread::spawn(move || loop {
                if exit_thread.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
                    break;
                }

                let mut guard = mutex_condvar.0.lock().unwrap();
                if let Some((duration, cb)) = guard.take() {
                    let _unused = mutex_condvar.1.wait_timeout(guard, duration).unwrap();
                    println!("Timer has fired!");
                    cb();
                } else {
                    let _unused = mutex_condvar.1.wait(guard).unwrap();
                }
            })
        };

        Self {
            thread_handle: Some(thread_handle),
            mutex_condvar,
            exit_thread,
        }
    }
}

impl AsyncTimer for AsyncTimerImpl {
    fn new() -> Self
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        AsyncTimerImpl::new()
    }

    fn abort_timeout(&self) {
        let _ = self.mutex_condvar.0.lock().unwrap().take();
        self.mutex_condvar.1.notify_one();
    }

    fn set_timeout(&self, duration: Duration, cb: Box<dyn Fn() + Send>) {
        let _ = self.mutex_condvar.0.lock().unwrap().replace((duration, cb));
        self.mutex_condvar.1.notify_one();
    }
}

impl<T: AsyncTimer> DeviceModel<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            timeout_counter: AtomicU64::new(0),
            timer: T::new(),
        }
    }

    fn set_next_timeout(&self) {
        let cb = {
            // This hack is only valid, as the device model and it's thread have a shorter
            // lifetime than the device model. This is enforced by control flow and not by
            // Rust's type system and lifetime logic.
            //
            // Otherwise, it is far from trivial to move a callback to the device model.
            let self_cursed: &'static DeviceModel<T> = unsafe { &*core::ptr::addr_of!(*self) };
            move || {
                self_cursed.on_timeout();
            }
        };
        let cb = Box::new(cb);
        self.timer.set_timeout(Duration::new(1, 0), cb);
    }

    fn on_timeout(&self) {
        self.timeout_counter.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
        println!("AsyncTimer called callback in DeviceModel");
    }
}

impl Drop for AsyncTimerImpl {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.exit_thread.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
        self.mutex_condvar.1.notify_one();
        self.thread_handle.take().unwrap().join().unwrap();
        println!("Stopped Thread");
    }
}

// Safety: DeviceModel uses interior mutability
unsafe impl<T: AsyncTimer> Send for DeviceModel<T> {}
unsafe impl<T: AsyncTimer> Sync for DeviceModel<T> {}

fn main() {
    let model = DeviceModel::<AsyncTimerImpl>::new();

    model.set_next_timeout();
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    model.set_next_timeout();
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    model.set_next_timeout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood fully your problem. If I am right, you are looking for an elegant way to set many asynchronous tasks (in separate threads) that can emit another tasks as well. And all must be done over the data defined in the fields of `DeviceModel`.

If so, I would recommend you to consider channels (https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std_misc/channels.html) and manage your `DeviceModel` this way:

```rust
struct DeviceModel {
    data: Arc<Mutex<Data>>,
    tx: Sender<Task>,
    rx: Receiver<Task>,
}
```

You should pass `data` into your tasks, so it can change there. And if a task needs to emit another tasks, it transfers the parameters of new tasks through the channel defined as `tx` and `rx` and the main thread spawns new threads. All logic regarding `data` is implemented in `Data`. Since Rust closures support `Send` trait, you can pass them directly in the channel (as part of `Task` structure in my example).

```rust
struct Task<F: FnOnce() + Send + 'static> {
    closure: F,
    duration: ...
    ...
}
```

I believe this pattern is quite clear and it may save you from errors and confusing code.

Comment: Hey! The problem is that `DeviceModel` and `AsyncTimer` are `no_std`, so there is no possibility to use sender/receiver directly. Luckily, I could find a solution using `Arc::new_cyclic`.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of `Arc::new_cyclic`, mentioned by @bk2204, I could solve my problem satisfyingly. The needed complexity is within reasonable limits.

I did one change, however: Instead of passing a `Box<Fn()>`, the callback is defined on the `AsyncTimer::on_timeout` method. This "feels" like a better design.

Code on Rust playground: [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=12239be8ea035af120eec96d3e84f2dd)

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, AtomicU64, Ordering};
use std::sync::{Arc, Condvar, Mutex, Weak};
use std::thread::{sleep, JoinHandle};
use std::time::Duration;

/// An async timer that is owned by a [`DeviceModel`].
trait AsyncTimer: 'static {
    fn new(device: Weak<DeviceModel>) -> Arc<Self>
    where
        Self: Sized;
    fn abort_timeout(&self);
    fn set_timeout(&self, timestamp: Duration);
    fn device(&self) -> Arc<DeviceModel>;
    fn on_timeout(&self) {
        self.device().on_timeout();
    }
}

/// A device that owns a [`AsyncTimer`].
struct DeviceModel {
    timeout_counter: AtomicU64,
    timer: Arc<dyn AsyncTimer>,
}

/// An implementation of [`AsyncTimer`] that creates a thread that fires the
/// configured timer events. It has a cyclic self-reference so that the thread
/// can access the timer itself as well to invoke the corresponding callback on
/// the device.
struct AsyncThreadTimer {
    device: Weak<DeviceModel>,
    // Option so that it can be joined on Drop.
    thread_handle: Option<JoinHandle<()>>,
    mutex_condvar: Arc<(Mutex<Option<Duration>>, Condvar)>,
    exit_thread: Arc<AtomicBool>,
}

impl AsyncThreadTimer {
    fn new(device: Weak<DeviceModel>) -> Arc<Self> {
        let mutex_condvar = Arc::new((Mutex::new(None), Condvar::new()));
        let exit_thread = Arc::new(AtomicBool::new(false));
        Arc::new_cyclic(|self_ref| Self {
            device,
            thread_handle: Some(Self::spawn_thread(
                mutex_condvar.clone(),
                exit_thread.clone(),
                self_ref.clone(),
            )),
            mutex_condvar,
            exit_thread,
        })
    }

    fn spawn_thread(
        mutex_condvar: Arc<(Mutex<Option<Duration>>, Condvar)>,
        exit_thread: Arc<AtomicBool>,
        self_ref: Weak<Self>,
    ) -> JoinHandle<()> {
        std::thread::spawn(move || loop {
            if exit_thread.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
                break;
            }

            let mut guard = mutex_condvar.0.lock().unwrap();
            if let Some(duration) = guard.take() {
                let _unused = mutex_condvar.1.wait_timeout(guard, duration).unwrap();

                if exit_thread.load(Ordering::SeqCst) {
                    break;
                }

                println!("Timer has fired!");
                self_ref
                    .upgrade()
                    .expect("the object should live at least as long as its managed thread")
                    .on_timeout();
            } else {
                let _unused = mutex_condvar.1.wait(guard).unwrap();
            }
        })
    }
}

impl AsyncTimer for AsyncThreadTimer {
    fn new(device: Weak<DeviceModel>) -> Arc<Self> {
        AsyncThreadTimer::new(device)
    }

    fn abort_timeout(&self) {
        let _ = self.mutex_condvar.0.lock().unwrap().take();
        self.mutex_condvar.1.notify_one();
    }

    fn set_timeout(&self, duration: Duration) {
        let _ = self.mutex_condvar.0.lock().unwrap().replace(duration);
        self.mutex_condvar.1.notify_one();
    }

    fn device(&self) -> Arc<DeviceModel> {
        self.device.upgrade().unwrap()
    }
}

impl DeviceModel {
    fn new<T: AsyncTimer>() -> Arc<Self> {
        Arc::new_cyclic(|self_ref| {
            let timer = T::new(self_ref.clone());
            Self {
                timeout_counter: AtomicU64::new(0),
                timer,
            }
        })
    }

    fn set_next_timeout(&self) {
        self.timer.set_timeout(Duration::new(1, 0));
    }

    fn on_timeout(&self) {
        self.timeout_counter.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
        println!("AsyncTimer called callback in DeviceModel");
    }
}

impl Drop for AsyncThreadTimer {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.exit_thread.store(true, Ordering::SeqCst);
        self.mutex_condvar.1.notify_one();
        self.thread_handle.take().unwrap().join().unwrap();
        println!("Stopped Thread");
    }
}

// Safety: DeviceModel uses interior mutability
unsafe impl Send for DeviceModel {}
unsafe impl Sync for DeviceModel {}

fn main() {
    let model = DeviceModel::new::<AsyncThreadTimer>();

    model.set_next_timeout();
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    model.set_next_timeout();
    // We should see just two fired timeouts because of this
    model.timer.abort_timeout();
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
    model.set_next_timeout();
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
}
```